# Zend Framework 2 Module to Sub domain mapping

Tags: php, zend-framework, module, routes, zend-framework2

I am working on a project with two modules as Web and Cms. I want to use sub domains with these modules.

`mydomain.com` -> Web Module

`cms.mydomain.com` -> Cms Module

I used below module.config.php files in each modules

**Web Module -> module.config.php**

```
<?php

return array(
     'controllers' => array(
         'invokables' => array(
             'Web\Controller\Index' => 'Web\Controller\IndexController',
         ),
     ),
     // The following section is new and should be added to your file
     'router' => array(
         'routes' => array(
             'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Hostname',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => 'mydomain.com',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Web\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Index',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),

         ),
     ),


     'view_manager' => array(
        'template_map' => array(
             'layout/layout' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/default.phtml',
        ),
         'template_path_stack' => array(
            'web' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
         ),
     ),
     'session' => array(
        'remember_me_seconds' => 2419200,
        'use_cookies' => true,
        'cookie_httponly' => true,
    ),
 );


?>
```

**CMS Module -> module.config.php**

```
<?php
return array(
     'controllers' => array(
         'invokables' => array(
             'Cms\Controller\Index' => 'Cms\Controller\IndexController',
             'Cms\Controller\User' => 'Cms\Controller\UserController',
         ),
     ),
     // The following section is new and should be added to your file
     'router' => array(
         'routes' => array(
            'cms' => array(
                'type' => 'Hostname',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => 'cms.mydomain.dev',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Cms\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                                'controller' => 'Index',
                                'action'     => 'index',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
             ),

         ),
     ),


     'view_manager' => array(
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/default' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/default.phtml',
            'layout/system' => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/system_layout.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
         'template_path_stack' => array(
             'cms' => __DIR__ . '/../view/script',
         ),
     ),
     'session' => array(
        'remember_me_seconds' => 2419200,
        'use_cookies' => true,
        'cookie_httponly' => true,
    ),
 );
?>
```

This doesn't work as expected. Web module `mydomain.com` shows it's layout but view content not loading. CMS also showing the web module when I try `cms.mydomain.com`. Could you please guide me where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

The router config looks OK to me. You may have just a typo in the domain name. In web module, it is mydomain.com whereas in cms module you have some mydomain.dev.

Web module view content not showing may be caused by another reason which has nothing to do with routing.